# Current status "minor review" what is next?

Tags: publications, journals, peer-review

I submitted a paper in a journal under Taylor and Francis and after the first review the status of the paper is "minor review". Both of the reviewers said that my manuscript can be accepted with some minor revisions. I am currently editing the paper according to their suggestions. My question is after I submit again will it go to the same reviewers or new reviewers will be assigned? How long will it take from a minor review to acceptance? I have no problem if it goes through multiple minor reviews but my main concern is to get acceptance notice since it is mandatory for my thesis defense, even "acceptance with minor review" status will work.

Comment: This was closed while I wrote an answer that gives some information not in the linked question... somewhat annoying that this was closed!

Comment: @Lewian I'd be happy to reopen if the OP can specify how their question is not contained in the duplicate one. If your answer instead contains details about the review process that have not been described in the duplicate, which is a canonical question exactly for these cases, and which can be of interest for the general case, I encourage you to propose an edit to the answer therein.

Comment: I had something about my personal experiences as editor at the specific stage the question here is about. Probably too focused on that stage for the other thread.

Comment: Update: i submitted minor revision on 6th and within few hours the admin made it "unsubstituted". Possibly he was the editor and he gave more suggestions. I again submitted on 10th and finally got accepted on 20th.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the editor for guidance on this. It is hard to predict how long any review will take since the time available to reviewers for this work varies so much and is usually unpaid. Whether it goes to the same reviewers or not is up to the editors. If they want things done quickly (not a given) then going back to the same reviewers (or a subset) helps move it along.

But perhaps you can get some assurance, though not a guarantee, that the paper will actually get published. Let the editor know why this is important to you at the moment and that you aren't just anxious as all authors tend to be.